# jasmine not working with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, jasmine, puppeteer

I'm trying to run a simple test in jasmine using puppeteer, however I can't get puppeteer to work when i use it in my test script:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

describe("Jasmine puppeteer", function() {

  let browser;
  let page;

  beforeAll(() => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('chrome://newtab');
    await page.screenshot({path: 'a.png'});
  })

  it("jasmine puppeteer", () => {
    expect(await page.title()).toBe("");
    done();
  });

  afterAll(() => {
  })
});
```

On running this script I get:

```
$ npm test spec/testspec.js

> test@0.0.1 test D:\sample
> jasmine "spec/testspec.js"

D:\sample\spec\testspec.js:10
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
                    ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at D:\sample\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:93:5
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

`npm test` simply points to `jasmine`. The test works fine if i comment puppeteer related code.

Answer (score 3):

`await` only works inside `async function`.

```
beforeAll((done) => {
    let screenshot = async function() {
        browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
        page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('chrome://newtab');
        await page.screenshot({ path: 'a.png' });
    }
    screenshot().then(done)
})
```

Comment: I think that your example is missing `done` callback.

Comment: you are right, i don't know more about `Jasmine`, i will fix the answer. thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't `done()` be inside screenshot  function after `page.screenshot`? Or `screenshot.then(done)`?

Comment: Both ok, but in my mine, `done()` is means `beforeAll` function finished, and before that, we can do anything like screen an other page.

Comment: But in your example is no guarantee that screenshot is created before calling `done()`. What's more, there is no guarantee that `page` is created and later in code inside `it` there is a reference to `page`.

Comment: You are right, I test it, And I think I have a wrong understanding of the `async/await`.I fix it. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Following the first answer I put all `awaits` inside `async` functions. However I still wasn't able to run the test script. Turns out async/await are not supported by jasmine according to [this github issue](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/923), some of the comments do suggest workarounds to fix that.

Resulting in the working script:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function testAsync(specFunction) {
  return (done) => {
      specFunction().then(() => {
          done();
      }).catch((error) => {
          done.fail(error);
      });
  };
}

describe("Jasmine puppeteer", function() {

  let browser;
  let page;

  beforeAll(testAsync(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://example.com');
    await page.screenshot({path: 'a.png'});
  }));

  it("jasmine puppeteer", testAsync(async () => {
    expect(await page.title()).toBe("");
  }));

  afterAll(() => {
  })
});
```

Comment: I never understood why should I jasmine over puppetter . [can you have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53459478/testing-puppeteer-with-jasmine)?

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like this 
‘’’
it("jasmine puppeteer",async  () => {
    expect(await page.title()).toBe("");
    done();
  });
‘’’