# Testing puppeteer with Jasmine?

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

We have a website that has many paths of flow (login , signup , payment ,etc)

We're using puppeteer scripts ( typescript via node)  to automate-testing our website behaviour (full flow) , and when we get an error (or unexpected result) we're sending email or some kind of alerts.

But I see that people [also use jasmine with puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48497986/859154).

For example :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

describe("Jasmine puppeteer", function() {

  let browser;
  let page;

  beforeAll(() => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('chrome://newtab');
    await page.screenshot({path: 'a.png'});
  })

  it("jasmine puppeteer", () => {
    expect(await page.title()).toBe("");
    done();
  });

  afterAll(() => {
  })
});
```

Using a testing framework over automated testing framework seems (to me) like `Test(Test())`

**Question**

Should we change our site approach testing to jasmin over puppeteer ? I mean , currently puepetteer provides a good way to test our site flow. Should we need to apply jasmine testing over our existing tests scripts ? I'm a bit confused about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jest with puppeteer for end to end testing. Jest is based on Jasmine framework. It is developed by Facebook and it’s quite popular now.

Answer (score 1):

puppeteer is not a testing framework.
puppeteer is a tool that automate browser.
you cannot make any assert with puppeteer, so you need a testing framework.
a good choise for puppeteer is jest,
because jest come out of the box with everything you need.
you can also use mocha and chai,
but i suggest jest because you can start to use immediately.